# is it possible to join a single table it self?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

this is the model function i am trying join the single database table it self the , parent::get  method fetch the data from the table !

```
public function get_with_parents($id=NULL,$single=FALSE){
$this->db->select('pages.*','p.slug as parent_slug','p.title as parent_title');
$this->db->join('pages as p','pages.parent_id=p.id','left');
return parent::get($id,$single);
}
```

this is the controller!!

```
$this->data ['pages'] = $this->Page_model->get_with_parents();
```

Comment: You can also use Raw SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your single tables is called `pages`, this should work -

```
$this->db->select('p1.title as ptitle','p.slug as parent_slug','p.title as parent_title');
$this->db->from('pages AS p1');
$this->db->join('pages AS p','p1.parent_id=p.id','left');
```

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'pages'

SELECT `pages`.* FROM (`pages` AS pages, `pages`) LEFT JOIN `pages` AS p ON `pages`.`parent_id`=`p`.`id` ORDER BY `order`

Filename: E:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.2.0\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$parent_slug

Comment: This means your query has worked. You need to figure out the reason behind this PHP error separately (or should be part of a separate question). Since your question was if it was possible to use self-join, do you consider my response as answer to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_with_parent($id = NULL,$sengle = FALSE)
{
   $this->db->select('pages.*,p.slug as parent_slug,p.title as parent_title')
   ->where("pages.language", $this->uri->segment(1))
   ->join('pages as p','pages.parent_id=p.id','left');
   return parent::get($id,$sengle);
}
```

or

```
public function get_with_parent ()
{
   $this->db->select('pages.*, p.slug as parent_slug, p.title as parent_title')
   ->where("pages.language", $this->uri->segment(1))
   ->join('pages as p', 'pages.parent_id=p.id', 'left');
   $query = $this->db->get('pages');
   return $query->result();
}
```